# Rank based on sequence of dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, row-number

I am having data as below

```
**Heading    Date**
A          2009-02-01
B          2009-02-03
c          2009-02-05
d          2009-02-06
e          2009-02-08
```

I need rank as below

```
Heading    Date           Rank
A          2009-02-01      1
B          2009-02-03      2
c          2009-02-05      1
d          2009-02-06      2
e          2009-02-07      3
```

As I need rank based on date. If the date is continuous the rank should be 1, 2, 3 etc. If there is any break on dates I need to start over with 1, 2, ...

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be 1, 1, 1, 2, 3?

Comment: Sample data as sqlfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5f4f8 .

Comment: Are dates ordered according to `heading`? Can there be more than one date per `heading`?

Comment: Also, last row in result contradicts sample above.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT heading, thedate
      ,row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY thedate) AS rn
FROM  (
   SELECT *, thedate - (row_number() OVER (ORDER BY thedate))::int AS grp
   FROM   demo
   ) sub;
```

While you speak of "rank" you seem to want the result of the window function [`row_number()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html).

1. Form groups of consecutive days (same date in `grp`) in subquery `sub`.
2. Number rows with another `row_number()` call, this time partitioned by `grp`.

One subquery is the bare minimum here, since window functions cannot be nested.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ca77f/2)

Note that I went with the second version of your contradictory sample data. And the result is as [@mu suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) in his comment.
Also assuming that there are no duplicate dates. You'd have to aggregate first in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is not correct answer, I am trying.. It is interesting..:) I am posting what I got so far: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5f4f8/3)

```
SELECT
    rank() over (order by thedate asc) as rank,
    heading, thedate
FROM 
    demo
Order by
    rank asc;
```

Now I am trying to get the break in dates. I don't know how? But may be these links useful

- [SQL — computing end dates from a given start date with arbitrary
  breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630139/sql-computing-end-dates-from-a-given-start-date-with-arbitrary-breaks)
- [How to rank in postgres query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265234/how-to-rank-in-postgres-query)

I will update if I got anything.

**Edit:**

I got this for mysql, I am posting this because it may helpful. Check [Emulate Row_Number()](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=1098)
Here

> Given a table with two columns i and j, generate a resultset that has
>   a derived sequential row_number column taking the values 1,2,3,... for
>   a defined ordering of j which resets to 1 when the value of i changes

Comment: Bangalore BLR - Bagmane Tech Park 2013-10-11 Data Centre 0 Bangalore BLR - Bagmane Tech Park 2013-10-11 BMS 0 Bangalore BLR - Bagmane Tech Park 2013-10-12 BMS 0 Bangalore BLR - Bagmane Tech Park 2013-10-15 BMS 3

I am having data lyk this..

If last column is zero the rank should be made based on all columns..If the date is continuous like 2013-10-11 ,2013-10-12 rank should be 1,2...

If there is any break in date 2013-10-11 ,2013-10-12 and 2013-10-15 again the rank should start from 1 for 2013-10-15

Answer (score 0):

Bangalore   BLR - Bagmane Tech Park    2013-10-11   Data Centre               0
Bangalore   BLR - Bagmane Tech Park    2013-10-11   BMS                       0
Bangalore   BLR - Bagmane Tech Park    2013-10-12   BMS               0
Bangalore   BLR - Bagmane Tech Park    2013-10-15   BMS               3

I am having data lyk this..

If last column is zero the rank should be made based on all columns..If the date is continuous
like 2013-10-11 ,2013-10-12 rank should be 1,2...

If there is any break in date   2013-10-11 ,2013-10-12 and  2013-10-15   again the rank should start from 1 for 2013-10-15

Comment: This should probably be another question (or an edit to this one), not an answer. But before you post the question add Postgres version, table definitions and explain what `should be made based on all columns` is supposed to mean.