# Aggregate continuous ranges of dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, aggregate-functions, window-functions

Let's say you have the following PostgreSQL sparse table listing reservation dates:

```
CREATE TABLE reserved_dates (
    reserved_days_id    SERIAL  NOT NULL,
    reserved_date       DATE    NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO reserved_dates (reserved_date) VALUES
    ('2014-10-11'),
    ('2014-10-12'),
    ('2014-10-13'),
    -- gap
    ('2014-10-15'),
    ('2014-10-16'),
    -- gap
    ('2014-10-18'),
    -- gap
    ('2014-10-20'),
    ('2014-10-21');
```

How do you aggregate those dates into continuous date ranges (ranges without gaps)? Such as:

```
 start_date | end_date
------------+------------
 2014-10-11 | 2014-10-13
 2014-10-15 | 2014-10-16
 2014-10-18 | 2014-10-18
 2014-10-20 | 2014-10-21
```

This is what I came up with so far, but I can only get `start_date` this way:

```
WITH reserved_date_ranges AS (
    SELECT reserved_date,
           reserved_date
           - LAG(reserved_date) OVER (ORDER BY reserved_date) AS difference
    FROM reserved_dates
)
SELECT *
FROM reserved_date_ranges
WHERE difference > 1 OR difference IS NULL;
```

Comment: Keyword is *calendar table* , in your case:: generate_series() left join YourTable, basically.

Comment: Alright, I would fill in the gaps with the in-between dates that way. How do I get the date ranges from that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```sql
SELECT min(reserved_date) AS start_date
     , max(reserved_date) AS end_date
FROM  (
   SELECT reserved_date
        , reserved_date - row_number() OVER (ORDER BY reserved_date)::int AS grp
   FROM   reserved_dates
   ) sub 
GROUP  BY grp
ORDER  BY grp;
```

1. Compute gap-less serial numbers in chronological order with the window function `row_number()`. Duplicate dates are not allowed. (I added a `UNIQUE` constraint in the fiddle.)

   If your `reserved_days_id` happens to be gap-less and in chronological order, you can use that directly instead. But that's typically *not* the case.
2. Subtract that from `reserved_date` in each row (after converting to `integer`). Consecutive days end up with the same date value `grp` - which has no other purpose or meaning than to form groups.
3. Aggregate in the outer query. Voilá.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9a058d0e835f39dbddb21a55bd31a28a)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ad4d4/1)</sub>

Similar cases:

- [Rank based on sequence of dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20063524/rank-based-on-sequence-of-dates/20064303#20064303)
- [Group by repeating attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010348/group-by-repeating-attribute/14016575#14016575)

Comment: This A seems hard to apply in general case for time series with a set resolution, e.g. 2 days or every 10 minutes. Timestamps would need to be cast to real values and float point operations aren't precise. Are there alternatives?

Comment: I take my words back. This solution works with timestamp columns akin to  `extract(epoch from timestamp) - extract(epoch from interval '1day')*row_number() over (order by timestamp)`

Comment: After all this years, I realized it is not duplicates-proof https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/31UdD6udUZqwQk43pRbGKZ/1

Comment: Use `dense_rank` instead of `row_number` if you happen to have duplicates.